# Pandoc HTML variables: `quotes` and `math`

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

Pandoc default HTML template contains these two variables:

- `quotes`,
- `math`.

How are they supposed to be used?

More specifically I see that `quotes` sets the values for the tag `<q>`. Is this tag used in markdown to HTML conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `quotes` variable, see @scoa.
As regards  the `math` variable, I found what follows.

When using MathML, that is the option `--mathml`, the code block:

```
$if(math)$
  $math$
$endif$
```

in the default HTML conversion template adds a portability script to the HTML output. 
Anyway, Chrome and Edge do not currently support MathML and Firefox seems to support it without this script.
So, for a custom template, removing the `$if(math)$ ...` code block will not affect MathML rendering.

When using MathJax, that is the option `--mathjax`,  `$if(math)$ ...`  adds to the HTML output the script block:

```
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML-full" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is always necessary to render the maths formulae.

When using the `--latexmathml`, a giant [script](http://math.etsu.edu/LaTeXMathML/), converting the LaTeX style math into MathML, is inserted by the `$if(math)$ ...` code block. Without this code block in the conversion template, the script is not inserted and the maths can't be rendered.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: they seem to be mostly obsolete legacies from previous versions of pandoc

### `quotes`

A little archeology of pandoc commits shows that 'quotes' was added when pandoc switched from using `<q>` tags to directly adding quotes signs. A new option, `--html-q-tags` was added to keep the previous behavior: the option wraps quotes in `<q>` and sets `quotes` to `true` so that a piece of css code is added as explained in the html template. See [this commit to pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/eebed6bc48c2e1b8c2da2e5b198e0164f76c0ab5) and this commit to [pandoc-templates](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/commit/40ef433abb89cb205ee25077fab343951caabe35). See the behavior with the following file:

```
"hello world"
```

This:

```
pandoc test.md -t html --smart --standalone
```

Produces (skipping the usual head, with no css affecting `<q>`)

```
<p>“hello world”</p>
```

While this

```
pandoc test.md -t html --standalone --html-q-tags --smart
```

produces (skipping the usual header)

```
  <style type="text/css">q { quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’"; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><q>hello world</q></p>
</body>
```

You have to use `--smart` though.

## `math`

It looks like this was introduced to include math rendering scripts inside the standalone file. See [this commit](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/56217f100404bc277c53518436ea93973c7705ac) from 2010. I think some command-line options picking non-(currently)-default math rendering systems, like `--mathml`, sets this variable to a value that actually makes sense (like copying the math rendering scripts). Try:

```
pandoc -t html --mathml
```